# Error when trying to run rspec Failure/Error: require 'test' LoadError: cannot load such file -- test

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails, rspec3

I am trying to run RSpec for Ruby on Rails. I am running Rails 5.0 I have installed the gem, have established a spec folder with some tests.

**I run following command on console**

```
$ rspec --init
create   spec/spec_helper.rb
create   .rspec
```

**I create file called 'test.rb'.**

```
class Test
end
```

**I create file called 'zombie_spec.rb'.**

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'test'

describe Test do
    it " Name Is Bapu." do
        # test = test.new
        # test.name.should == 'bapu'
    end
end
```

**Then after I run this command.**

```
rspec spec/lib/zombie_spec.rb
```

**It shows error ⬇**

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/lib/zombie_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: require 'test'

LoadError:
  cannot load such file -- test
# ./spec/lib/zombie_spec.rb:2:in `require'
# ./spec/lib/zombie_spec.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.


Finished in 0.00026 seconds (files took 0.40148 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples
```

How do I resolve this so that I can start running tests?

Comment: You should require `zombie`, not `test`. Your file is called `zombie.rb` not `test.rb`

Comment: am sry its my mistake I create a test.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file paths are off, you either need to have `zombie_spec.rb` in the `spec/` folder instead of `spec/lib/` or you need to move `test.rb` into the `lib/` folder instead of being in the `/` project root folder.